# Массовое удаление кусочков текста в php файлах

Tags: php

Всем привет, наверно кто то сталкивался с заражением сайта, когда кусочки зашифрованного php кода попадали во все php файлы, подскажите пожалуйста, чем вы массово удаляли этот кусочек текста из всех файлов сайта?

Comment: Обычно я восстанавливаю из бекапа, который не забываю периодически делать в ручном режиме или скриптом.

Comment: учтем! Jino держит бекапы только за последние 6 дней.....всего 3 штуки. вирус же проник как раз чуть раньше...

Comment: вернее делает их каждые 3 дня, и хранит только 3 бекапа

Comment: регуляркой по всем файлам

Comment: Обычно эти куски пихают в конец файла, просто надо резать конец файла просчитав количество символов, или регуляркой.... приведите код и где эти куски записаны? в начале, конце, середине?

Comment: А при чем тут Jino? Вам разве на хосте не дали доступ в админпанель? Теперь у вас вариантов не много: или ручками выковыривать, или парсить каждый документ и регуляркой выискивать этот код (при том, что он должен быть везде одинаковый). Кроме того, если конфигурационные файлы исправить вручную, то остальные можно по FTP переписать поверх. Это не должно повлиять на работу.

Comment: jino - это я про бекапы!
а кусочки кода в начале файлов сразу после <?php
вспомнил я софтину классную! написал в ответе!

Comment: @Deonis, зачем регуляркой вытаскивать одинаковый текст?)) Я лечил через `str_replace('нужный_кусок')` по всем .php/.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вспомнил! [Handy File Tool](http://www.handyfiletool.com/).